# Why does ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK()'s return not begin with Sunday?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following (MySQL) table called "tweets":

```
tweet_id   created_at
---------------------
1          1298027046
2          1298027100
5          1298477008
```

I want MySQL returning the number of tweets per day of the week; taking the above data it should return:

```
Sunday  1
Monday  2
```

I now have the following query  to accomplish this:

```
SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) AS tweets, DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) AS day 
FROM tweets 
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(day)
```

This however returns a list that starts with Wednesday:

```
Wednesday 2019
Tuesday   2072
Monday     932
Sunday    1433
Saturday  4321
Friday     643
Thursday  1542
```

How is this list ordered? Why not just Sun to Sat and how * can * I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAYOFWEEK` takes a date (`'2011-02-26'`), but you're giving it a day name (`'Saturday'`).

Comment: Thanks, so true....for some reason I completely overlooked that and assumed I had something like FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`) AS day".

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the order clause like this

```
order by dayofweek(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
```